# How do I read QR Code using Google Actions

Tags: actions-on-google

I am building Google Actions using Actions SDK, I would like action to read values from QR code. The solution shouldn't require to install any other additional app. Using the existing Google Assistant the value in QR code should be read and sent as Intents.

Answer (score 1):

Google Actions do not support any interactions with QR codes during the conversation. If you wish to create a QR code that links into your action you can use [action links](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/action-links). With action links you can generate a URL that directs the user to your action in the Google Assistant app.

You could create a QR code that has this action link as it's content and when a user scans this action link with a scanner app they can browse to the URL, which will start your action.